# JavaScript detect pressed enter key before reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a script that detects when the user adds information into a form ( for example when one user sends a message to another ). If the user added information and tries to leave the page i use an onbeforeload function to warn the user.

The problem i have now is that in the message example above the user can send a message by pressing the enter button on the keyboard. So i need to detect whether the user pressed the enter key on the keyboard and if so, i need to stop the function.

Is there a way for me to find out within this function whether the user pressed the enter key before leaving the page?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    try {
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = warningOutput;
        }
        return warningOutput;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `event.keyCode == 13` is what you are looking for?

Comment: I have been thinking about that as well. But will it still work before the page loads?

Comment: Nope! Only on input events!

Comment: So do you have an idea if there is a way for me to detect if the user pressed the enter key before the reload?

Comment: So, when the user send a message by pressing the enter button on the keyboard, is it redirecting to another page?

Comment: There are two forms i want to use this function in. One redirects the user and the other one just reloads the page.